# android.view.WindowLeaked in onClick code

Tags: android, android-dialog

I think the error is occurs at this code:

```
goDirect.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(scanActivity.this);
                        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.serial_popup, null);

                        mBuilder.setView(mView);
                        final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

                        dialog.show();

                        Button authButton = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.authButton);


                        authButton.setOnClickListener(
                                new View.OnClickListener(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(scanActivity.this, itemSetActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(myIntent);
                                        finish();

                                        overridePendingTransition(R.xml.madefadein, R.xml.splashfadeout);
                                    }
                                }
                        );
                    }
                }
        );
```

This code return windowLeaked exception. But I can't solve it.

To solve windowLeaked Exception, I have to use `dialog.dismiss` and change dialog's value to null. To use `dismiss()` in inner class, I declared dialog to final. but declare final, I can't change dialog's value to null. How to solve this error? or Is there any solution to don't declare dialog to final?

I'm sorry I'm not fluent in English.

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.dh.qrock.scanActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{21f703da V.E..... R....... 0,0-1025,904} that was originally added here
                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                     at com.example.dh.qrock.scanActivity$4.onClick(scanActivity.java:217)
                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19772)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5228)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
Application terminated.
```

This is my log. 
scanActivity:217 is showDialog() code.

use dismiss log.

```
09/11 19:15:37: Launching app
Cold swapped changes.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.dh.qrock/com.example.dh.qrock.IntroActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 26200 on device foxconn-tg_l800s-PHXGLMD5A1102221
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.dh.qrock, real application class is null.
W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.example.dh.qrock/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.example.dh.qrock/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex) with checksum 0x0b3e0e9d in OatFile /data/data/com.example.dh.qrock/cache/slice-slice_5-classes.dex
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
D/Atlas: Validating map...
I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.020_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
              OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
              Build Date: 03/04/15 Wed
              Local Branch: mybranch8102437
              Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.14
              Local Patches: NONE
              Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.020 + 68ecddf + 5d22558 + bf8c1a3 + 746ac28 +  NOTHING
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@208829d2 time:119368343
D/AudioManager: playSoundEffect effectType:0
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.dh.qrock time:119368871
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@35a99f90 time:119369044
D/AudioManager: playSoundEffect effectType:0
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.dh.qrock time:119377512
I/System.out: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2VtYWlsIjoidGVzdEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE1MDUxMjQ5NDcsImV4cCI6MTUwNTcyOTc0NywiaXNzIjoieW91bmdoLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6InVzZXJJbmZvIn0.gtxYxypnPuCjpcxQDT1yOV-2y-8GArV0eIaFnPTTmhI
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@28652c6f time:119377852
D/AudioManager: playSoundEffect effectType:0
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.dh.qrock time:119378320
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:801
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 801
I/art: DexFile_isDexOptNeeded failed to open oat file '/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@data@com.google.android.gms@app_chimera@m@00000015@DynamiteModulesB_GmsCore_prodlmp_xxhdpi_release.apk@classes.dex' for file location '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000015/DynamiteModulesB_GmsCore_prodlmp_xxhdpi_release.apk': Failed to open oat filename for reading: No such file or directory
E/Camera: JK: version=V00.13.01.00
          ������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
E/Camera: JK: state=ready
          ��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@515763c time:119379342
D/AudioManager: playSoundEffect effectType:0
D/AudioManager: playSoundEffect effectType:0
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.dh.qrock time:119381058
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@23e82471 time:119381154
D/Camera: app passed NULL surface
```

Comment: change dialog.show();  to if(!yourActivity.isFinishing()) dialog.show(); and try

Comment: @Raghavendra It says Non-static method can't be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Can u just try (!isFinishing()) { dialog.show(); }

Comment: @Raghavendra It works. but It don't show popup window.

Comment: Oh It works. but still return windowLeaked exception.

Comment: can u post error log..

Comment: @Raghavendra I added sorry.

Comment: which is the line at scanActivity.java:217

Comment: @Raghavendra `dialog.show()` here. In `GoDirect.setOnClickListener()`

Comment: Posted an answer can u try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can u try this,

```
if(!isFinishing())
   dialog.show();

Button authButton = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setOnClickListener(
  new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
           dialog.dismiss();
       }

       Intent myIntent = new Intent(scanActivity.this, itemSetActivity.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
      finish();

      overridePendingTransition(R.xml.madefadein, R.xml.splashfadeout);
   }
 }
);
```

Comment: Does it load the itemSetActivity screen?

Comment: may be this is associated with camera code. may be I must stop camera too.. .

Comment: I don't know but can u see whther the itemSetActivity activity is loaded or not?

Comment: I can't see itemSetActivity. It shows only white Screen. I added the log when using your code. Confirm that.

Comment: Can u try by adding sample layout with a textview and load that screen instead of itemSetActivity to test once ?

Comment: I have tested the code looks fine.. But in ur case itemSetActivity activity is hanging.. may be stuck in loading something. check what r u doing in it

Comment: I tried... But it still returns white Screen. I will try another solution myself. really thanks for helping me!

Comment: Glad! happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to declare dialog as final and use them to show or dismiss.
But you should always enclose dialog show or dismiss in try catch because the parent of dialog show may vanish and you still could not close it.
Something like below.

```
 try{
     showDialog();
 }catch(Exception e){

 }
```